# clojure for loop, store the values in a set or map

Tags: loops, functional-programming, clojure, immutability

This one has been bothering me for a while now,
How should we store a value in a set or map in a for loop?

```
(let [s #{}]
     (for [ i (range 10)
            j (range 10) ]
      (into s [i j])))
```

i know this will not work, but i want a functionality similar to this , where the set will finally contain [0 0] [0 1]...[0 9] [1 0]...[9 9]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks all , for the responses.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need to turn your expression inside-out:

```
(let [s #{}]
  (into s (for [i (range 10) 
                j (range 10)] 
            [i j])))
```

The thing to realize here is that [`for`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for) returns a value (a lazy sequence) unlike for-loops in more imperative languages like Java and C.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want?

```
(into #{} (for [i (range 10) j (range 10)]
  [i j]))
;-> #{[2 1] [3 2] [4 3] [5 4] [6 5] [7 6] [8 7] [9 8] [1 0]
;     [2 2] [3 3] [4 4] [5 5] [6 6]...
```

And if you just want the list as a set:

```
(set (for [i (range 10) j (range 10)]
  [i j]))
```

You will end up with a set of pairs.

Answer (score 5):

*Generally* when you want to return a set or a map or other 'single value' that isn't a seq from a 'repeated' generalized operation on a seq, using `reduce` is more idiomatic/straightforward than `loop/recur`, and `for` always returns a seq (not a set or map).

```
(reduce conj #{} (for [i (range 10) j (range 10)] [i j]))
```

note that (for ..) here is only used to produce a seq containing all the values to compile into the single result **set**. Or, for example:

```
(reduce + 0 (range 100))
=> 4950
```

Answer (score 0):

clojure has a several great systems for managing mutable state. in this case you may want an [atom](http://clojure.org/atoms) containing a set

your other options are:

- a [ref](http://clojure.org/refs) if more than one change needs to made (coordinated many threads)
- a [var](http://clojure.org/vars) if this will be single threaded (a var may work just as well here as an atom)
- an [agent](http://clojure.org/agents) if you wanted to set the value of s asynchronously

of course `for` returns a sequence already so you may just want

```
 (into #{} (for [ i (range 10)
                  j (range 10) ]
             [i j]))
```

Comment: The first code snippet here doesn't make any sense, as far as I can tell? It's not a valid way to use `swap!`, and as you later mention it's not a good idea anyway.

Comment: the first snipit was not really the point of the answer anyway so I just removed it. posing with out testing *tisk tisk*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use some transient data structure in this scenario.

```
(let [s (transient #{})]
 (for [ i (range 10)
        j (range 10) ]
  (assoc! s i j)))
(persistent! s)
```

Just a code sample, not tested.

Comment: This is not correct. From [the docs for transients](http://clojure.org/transients): " Note in particular that transients are not designed to be bashed in-place. You must capture and use the return value in the next call. In this way, they support the same code structure as the functional persistent code they replace".